# JQUERY - Dynamically added list element with textarea not returning .val() when event listener is triggered

Tags: jquery, textarea, event-listener

I am using jQuery to dynamically add a list element to and unordered list. The element contains a thumbnail photograph and a textarea.

As there may be more than one of these elements in the list each element is assigned a unique id as is each textarea.

no matter what I try I cannot get the original contents or changed contents of the textarea to be returned.

The structure of the page is as follows :

```
<script id='SELECT' type='x-tmpl-mustache'>
    <div data-role='page' id='{{inspectionId}}-{{question.questionId}}' data-theme='c' class='{{questionClass}}' data-job='{{jobId}}' data-inspection='{{inspectionId}}' data-question='{{question.questionId}}' data-prev='{{inspectionId}}-{{question.previousQuestion}}' data-next='{{inspectionId}}-{{question.nextQuestion}}'>
        <div data-role='header' data-add-back-btn='false' data-position='fixed' data-theme='d'>
            <a href='#{{questionBackHREF}}' class='ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-left'>{{inspectionId}}</a>
              <h1>{{question.questionId}}</h1>
              <span class='ui-li-count'>{{question.livePage}}</span>
        </div><!-- /header--> 
        <div data-role='main' class='ui-content'>
            <form action='' id='form{{inspectionId}}-{{question.questionId}}'>
            <ul data-role='listview' id='ul{{inspectionId}}-{{question.questionId}}' class='ui-listview' data-theme='d' data-inset='false'>
                <li data-role='list-divider' data-theme='d'>
                    Section: {{section.title}}
                </li>
                <li data-role='list-divider' data-theme='d'> 
                    {{question.label}}
                </li>
                <li data-role='list-divider' class='ui-field-contain' data-theme='c'>
                    <select name='select-choice-0' id='select-choice-0' name='answer' class='mySelection' data-theme='c'>
                        <option data-placeholder='false'>{{question.answer}}</option>
                        {{#question.values}}
                            <option value='{{.}}'>{{.}}</option>
                        {{/question.values}}
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li data-role='list-divider' class='ui-field-contain' data-theme='c'>
                    <label for='notes'>Notes:</label>
                    <textarea id='notes' name='notes' class='notes' placeholder='Enter any notes here.'>{{question.notes}}</textarea>
                </li>
                <li data-role='list-divider' class='ui-field-contain' data-theme='d'>
                    Question Photographs
                </li>


                ***<li class='ui-field-contain listImage' id='{{imageId}}' image='{{image}}' data-job='{{thisJob}}' data-question='{{question}}' data-theme='d' data-icon='delete'>
                    <a href='#'>
                    <img src='{{image}}' class='img'></img>
                    <textarea type='text' id='imageNotes{{imageId}}' name='imageNotes' class='imageNotes{{imageId}}' placeholder='Notes.' data-theme='d'>{{notes}}</textarea>
                    </a>
                </li><!-- /list-item -->***


                <li data-role='list-divider' id='bottom-divider{{inspectionId}}-{{question.questionId}}' class='ui-field-contain' data-theme='d'>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </form>
        </div><!-- /content-->
        <div data-role='footer' id='footer' data-position='fixed' data-id='quesfooter' data-theme='d'>
            <div data-role='navbar' data-theme='d'>
                <ul>
                    <li data-theme='d'><a href='#jobs' data-icon='home'></a></li>
                   <li data-theme='d'><a href='#' onclick='takePicture();' id='cameraButton' data-icon='camera'></a></li>
                   <li><a href='#{{question.questionId}}-new-alert' data-icon='plus' data-theme='d'>New Alert</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
</script>
```

The event listener is as follows :

```
$(document).on('click', '.listImage', function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var job = $(this).data('job');
    var question = $(this).data('question');
    var notes = $(this).find("#imageNotes"+id).val();
    console.log(id);  //returns the id correctly.
    console.log(job); //returns the data correctly.
    console.log(question);  //returns the data correctly.
    console.log(notes);   //returns undefined.
}
```

Comment: is there type? 'notes? should be notes

Comment: You've a typo in console.log('notes); (note extra quote), your code should work if you've the right id's.

Comment: @TechBreak@Zakaria   sorry about the quote.  It was bad copy paste edit on my part when copying the code to here.  There is no issue with quotes in my code and it doesn't return the value from the textarea.  I have corrected the event listener code example here to correctly reflect what I have running in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do following,

```
var notesEl = "#imageNotes"+id;
```

And try to find as follows,

```
$(this).find(notesEl).val();
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me @TechBreak.  Unfortunately your suggestion didn't work.  It still returned undefined.  This one really has me stumped.